# Did I implement the right if statement in this character limit counter?

Tags: javascript, html

With this code, I’m trying to implement a character limit counter and I want the counter to say “Over!” in red letters when it reaches 0 but go back to counting when the user deletes characters.

This is my code so far, but I feel as if I used the wrong `if` statement, because it doesn’t seem to work correctly.

```
<textarea id="ta" rows="1" style="width:340px;"
  onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.ta,this.form.countDisplay);"
  onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.ta,this.form.countDisplay);"></textarea>
<input readonly type="text" name="countDisplay" size="3" maxlength="3" value="15">
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Preview</button>
<p id="go"></p>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ta").value;
    document.getElementById("go").innerHTML = x;
  }
  if (function myFunction() < 0) {
    document.getElementById("go").innerHTML = "Over!"; // tried implementing the red and the alert
  }
</script>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wtsa4L8x/)

Comment: So is the idea that the counter decrements every character you type until you run out?  I'm not seeing the textCounter function.  What is it doing?  Also, myFunction() does not return a value so I think it will probably not cause your IF condition to run.

Comment: Instead of `this.form.ta` you can simply do `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   function myFunction() {
       var x = document.getElementById("ta").value;
       document.getElementById("go").innerHTML = x;
       return x;
   }
```

you didn't return anything in myFunction()

in your if statement, remove the "function" keyword:

```
   if (myFunction() < 0) {
       document.getElementById("go").innerHTML="Over!";

    }
```

**EDIT**

Hi use this code:

**HTML**

```
 <form>
<textarea id="ta" rows="1" style="width:340px;"onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.ta,this.form.countDisplay);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.ta,this.form.countDisplay);"></textarea>

<input readonly type="text" name="countDisplay" size="3" maxlength="3" value="15">

<p id="go"></p>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var maxAmount = 15;
function textCounter(textField, showCountField) {
    if (textField.value.length > maxAmount) {
        textField.value = textField.value.substring(0, maxAmount);
    } else {
        showCountField.value = maxAmount - textField.value.length;
    }
    myFunction(showCountField.value);
}

function myFunction(value) {
    if(value<=0)
    {
        document.getElementById("go").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red'>Over!!</span>";
    }
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("go").innerHTML = value;
    }
}
```

I revised your code, remove the preview button and "Over!!" will automatically appear when count reach 0.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bh3r77pe/

Comment: Thank you but it still didnt change or "Over!" didnt show up

Comment: wait Im updating your fiddle, there are lots of mistake there.

Comment: OOMMMGGGEEEE THANK YOU YESS Friend indeed we should share info lol

Comment: Oh yeah one more thing you kinda made my preview button go away

Comment: wanna put it back? okay wait I'll put it back

Comment: fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bh3r77pe/2/     
just remove the 
myFunction(showCountField.value);
inside textCounter() function to see the button working.